# MySQL user export PASSWORD is showing up as <secret>

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, import, export, users

I am trying to export all users from old MySQL server to new.

All the methods that I tried shows the PASSWORD as `<secret>`

1. pt-show-grants
2. phpMyAdmin 4.8.1
3. https://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server/13050#13050

Someone, please point me to the updated answer to this very old question?

Server version: 5.6.27-log - MySQL 
(AWS RDS)

Answer (score 0):

See what you get from

```
mysqldump ... mysql user
```